# changed the name of the computer - SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql, ssms

i changed the computer name, and entered this commands in SQL server management studio  (ssms)

```
sp_dropserver <old_name>;   
sp_addserver <new_name>, local;
```

i press this query

```
select * from sys.servers
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMeYb.png)

is this okay? the location, provider string, catalog is NULL?

How can i know if everything changed according to the new Server name?
do i need to reinstall SSMS again?

Answer (score 1):

The code you ran to change the server name looks correct assuming you have a default instance.  If the results of [Select @@servername] and [Select * from sys.servers] returns the same name you changed it to, then it was changed successfully.  The fact that the columns location, provider_string, and catalog contain NULL in the results appears not to be an issue (The same exists in my environment).  You can use this MS article as reference:  [Rename a computer which hosts sql server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)